# Fix- DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
create procedure St_Proc_GetUserReportforCurrentDayTask                  
@userID int                  
as                  
    Begin                  
        set NoCount on;                  
        DECLARE @TODAY DATE                    
        SET @TODAY = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)                  
        select  CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate,101) + RIGHT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate , 100 ) ,7) as Date,                   
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectName as Region ,                  
        County.CountyName as County,                  
        WorkType.WorkTypeName as WorkType,                  
        Task.TaskName as Task,      
        Production.VolumeProcessed as 'Volumes Processed',                  
        Production.TimeSpent as 'Duration(HH:MM)'                  
        from Production                   
        inner join RegionAndProjectInfo                  
        on                  
        RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectID=Production.RegionProjectID                  
        inner join County                  
        on                   
        County.CountyID=Production.CountyID                  
        inner join WorkType                  
        on                  
        WorkType.WorkTypeID=Production.WorkTypeID                  
        inner join Task                  
        on                  
        Task.TaskID=Production.TaskID                  
        where Production.UserID=@userID and CalendarDate >= @TODAY                  
    End
```

This is my stored procedure and i am executing this stored procedure and saving the result in a dataset and then binding a grid with this dataset.

```
private void BindGridOnPageLoad()
    {
        _production = new EmployeeQuotientCL.Production();
        _userEcode = Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]);
        int _userID = _production.GetUserIDFromDB(_userEcode);
        dsUserTaskDetails = _production.GetTabularUsertaskDetails(_userID);
        BindGridView(dsUserTaskDetails);
    }
```

Up to here every thing is fine .Then i got requirement to show Duration(HH:MM) total in the footer of the grid view.I had added following code in the page:-

```
<div id="gridview">
            <asp:GridView ID="GVUserEnteredDetails" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="mGrid"  CellSpacing="2"   onselectedindexchanged="GVUserEnteredDetails_SelectedIndexChanged" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">                  
            </asp:GridView>
```

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            tp += Convert.ToDecimal(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row["[Duration(HH:MM)]"]);
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Total Hours : ";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = tp.ToString("c");
            e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Font.Bold = true;

        }
    }
```

But when i am debugging i m getting this error:- "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Duration'." What the mistake i m doing and how to fix it? Any suggestion and help will be helpful for me.

Stack Trace:-

> [ArgumentException: Column '[Duration(HH:MM)]' does not belong to table Table.]
>   System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) +2124943
>   System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) +13
>   EQ.Associates.Production.GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EQ\EQ\Associates\Production.aspx.cs:112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +181
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3896
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +66
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>   EQ.Associates.Production.BindGridView(DataSet ds) in C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EQ\EQ\Associates\Production.aspx.cs:603
>   EQ.Associates.Production.BindGridOnPageLoad() in C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EQ\EQ\Associates\Production.aspx.cs:593
>   EQ.Associates.Production.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EQ\EQ\Associates\Production.aspx.cs:78
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Comment: Are you binding the right table to the `GridView` ?

Comment: Yes and i specified in my question that till databinding and displaying only grid every thing is working fine but as i had tried to add footer then i get this error .

Comment: Bit surprising, What does your `DataSource` show `Duration...` (hope the procedure is the same as above you are executing)

Comment: Yeah the same procedure i m using and in Datagrid the Column Header Name showing as  : Date,Region,County,Work Type,Task,Volumes Processed, Duration(HH:MM)

Comment: So the only change you made was adding the `RowDataBound` event ?

Comment: Some time we miss minor things also and we are not thinking of it, i think i find out the problem, Actually the data inside Duration[HH:MM] is storing data in HH:MM format so suppose it is taking value like 02:30 and when we are converting it to Decimal or integer, here the conversion fails .Now i have to find that how to add these values and get accurate sum count. If have any suggestion or ideas do share .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments you are facing trouble in the Decimal parse of the data you have represented as HH:mm

you should be using a `TimeSpan` to sum all these values instead of a decimal. (`TimeSpan` has parse exact functionality from 4.0 but if you are on a lesser version)

Try doing it in this fashion

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact("02:30", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
// instead of 02:30 you would have the string from your column passed in

// you can add up the values in this fashion
ts.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("08:30", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
```

The Resultant Timespan you can use to display it the format you choose as it would also have number of days too or you can always show `ts.TotalMinutes`

Hope this is what you were looking out for else please update for the relevant part

Comment: Yes , actually this i am looking for. Now i can populate the total in the footer . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using sqare bracket around your column name as it is containing special characters. like,

```
 tp += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "[Duration(HH:MM)]"));
```

Comment: Done as per you but this this i get this exception "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: can you post detailed exception stacktrace?

Comment: You can even try: tp += Convert.ToDecimal(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row["[Duration(HH:MM)]"). But it assumes that you are using Datatable or Dataset as datasource.

Comment: Updated the question and mentioned the Stack trace also there.

Comment: It seems that .Net is assigning some different name to your datacolumn. Just check what name it is assigning in debug mode and replace with that in the above statement.